# C code keeps flashing errors, wondering if I might get a hand here?

Tags: c, grid, malloc, sizeof

I'm learning C and I think am falling in love but my new found love is freaking me out in this simple(supposedly) code. I'm just trying to print a 2D grid to be filled by integers. No matter what I changed, it kept giving same `int` related errors. Any help please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* malloc_grid - create a 2D array of integers */

int **malloc_grid(int width, int height)
{
    int i, j;
    int **arr;

    if (width < 1 || height < 1)
        return (NULL);

    arr = (int **)malloc(height * sizeof(int *));
    if (arr == NULL)
    {
        free(arr);
        return (NULL);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = (int *)malloc(width * sizeof(int));
        if (arr[i] == NULL)
        {
            for (; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                free(arr[i]);
            }
            free(arr);
            return (NULL);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++)
            arr[i][j] = 0;
    }

    return (arr);
}

/* main - program entry point */
int main(void) 
{
    printf("%d", malloc_grid(int 6, int 4));
    return 0;
}
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me. What's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "flashing errors"? Can you share the exact error message?

Comment: uhm...Blaze can u share how u got it working without the compiler errors?

Comment: If you get compiler errors, it would be a good idea to include these messages into your question.

Comment: You're totally right Gerhardh. I take corrections, next time I sure will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some high-level languages like Python, you can throw whatever you like at the `print` command and it will attempt to do something sensible with it.

C is not one of those languages. You need to be more precise.

First of all `int 6, int 4` makes no sense. Your compiler will have told you about this. Just write `6, 4` if those are the numbers you want.

Second, `%d` is a format specifier that expects an integer argument. But you're passing a pointer to a pointer to an integer. Again, this makes no sense. If you want to print out the entire array, you'll have to print each element separately. Something like this, perhaps:

```
int main(void) 
{
    int i, j, **grid;
    grid = malloc_grid(6,4);
    if (grid == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
        for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
            printf("%3d ", grid[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to declare the type of arguments when you calling a function. 
 `printf("%d", malloc_grid(6,4));`